Creating react project fails (following tailwind guide)
I am curently trying to set-up a react project with Tailwind for aschool asignment. Unfotunately due to something going wrong behind the scenes I get a list of errors after executing the command. This results in the project being unusable right from the start becouse some libarrys are missing. Does anyone know what could be cousing this and what I could try to fix the problem?
The errors are the following
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...


added 1320 packages in 47s

265 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

Initialized a git repository.

Installing template dependencies using npm...
npm error code ERESOLVE
npm error ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm error
npm error While resolving: programmeren6frontend2024@0.1.0
npm error Found: react@19.0.0
npm error node_modules/react
npm error   react@"^19.0.0" from the root project
npm error
npm error Could not resolve dependency:
npm error peer react@"^18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@13.4.0
npm error node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm error   @testing-library/react@"^13.0.0" from the root project
npm error
npm error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm error this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm error
npm error
npm error For a full report see:
npm error C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-12-19T13_15_32_824Z-eresolve-report.txt
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-12-19T13_15_32_824Z-debug-0.log
`npm install --no-audit --save @testing-library/jest-dom@^5.14.1 @testing-library/react@^13.0.0 @testing-library/user-event@^13.2.1 web-vitals@^2.1.0` failed


I tried to execute this command inside of my schoo folder: npx create-react-app programmeren6frontend2024



cd programmeren6frontend2024



I tried to execute the same code but in the C drive root folder instead
I tried forcing the lastes version: npx create-react-app@latest . --use-npm
I tried uninstalling create react to reset it: npm uninstall -g create-react-ap
npm uninstall create-react-app
Check a tutorial video (which gives me the same steps and commands from the tailwind installation guid)


If there is no mandate, can you try using next.js https://nextjs.org/ instead of create react app?

you need to fix dependencies version conflict. Tailwind does not affect on this

Thanks for the fast responses.
@ch4nd4n Unfortunately one of the requirements that my school sets for this asignment is that I can only use librarys that they allow me to use. For any other libary I will have to ask permission. The allowed libarys are the following:
• react
• react-dom
• react-icons
• react-router
• tailwindcss
• vite
• jwt-decode

@MaksatRahmanov Could you clarify how I do this? As stated before I have tried to reinstall npm 22 again but this did not fix the problem. Is there a other proces I can try and if so how?

I posted answer. Please update your post and attach package.json file so I can edit my answer if needed. Let me know if my solution worked for you

What I understood from post and error logs is that in your package.json file you have @testing-library/react: ^13.x.x dependency. This dependency itself depends on react: ^18.x.x dependency. And it seems that in your package.json you have react: ^19.x.x.
So "testing library" depends on react package version 18 but you have react version 19 installed.
You can try to:

upgrade @testing-library/react to latest version which supports react v19 (read their documentation)
set react version to 18.x.x and leave testing library version as is

